# Вывод массива структур

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
struct scientist
{
char name[20];
char surname[20];
};
struct scientist physic[] = { {"Джеймс","Максвелл"},
                            {"Томас","Юнг"},
                            {"Джеймс","Максвелл"},
                            {"Генри","Кавендиш"},
                            {"Джон","Флеминг"},
                            {"Иоганн","Бернулли"},
                            {"Генри","Джозеф"},
                            {"Джеймс","Уотсон"},
                            {"Томас","Эдисон"},
                            {"Иоганн","Кеплер"} };

printf("%c",physic[2].name);
}
```

Почему выводится результатом символ `, а не "Джеймс"? В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Я уверен, что вы имели в виду

```
printf("%s",physic[2].name);
       ^^^
```

вместо

```
printf("%c",physic[2].name);
       ^^^^
```

И вам нужно активизировать локаль для русских символов.

Comment: пишу в кодировке OEM866, при замене %с на %s программа компилируется, но вообще не запускается.
"Прекращена работа a.exe..." После этого редактировать и компилировать вообще не выходит до перезагрузки (permision denied).
Юзаю компилятор mingw, пишу в notepad++

Comment: @user193688 permision denied не имеет отношения к самой C - программе. Возможно, вы записали загрузочный модуль в папку, в которой нет разрешения на запуск программ.

Comment: это из-за процесса  a.exe, который "приостановлен", но закрыть его нельзя - нет прав. taskkill тоже не помогает. Только перезагрузка.

Comment: это уже другой вопрос, а касательно самой программы - она работает, спасибо. глупую ошибку допустил  опять

Comment: @user193688 Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)